# Скриншот экрана пользователя через js

Tags: javascript, html

Кто-нибудь знает как на чистом js, без применения различных библиотек, выполнить скриншот экрана пользователя.

Хочу собрать снимки экранов пользователей, чтобы иметь лучшее представление о том как отображается страница.

Выполнить скриншот, получить строчку для того чтобы ее возможно было записать в таблицу.

Затем просто взять строчку и через js, вывести в виде изображения.

Скриншот окна браузера это круто, но круче будет если скриншот будет всего экрана пользователя) Если возможно.

Comment: https://metrika.yandex.ru/promo/webvisor

Comment: @De.Minov если я правильно понимаю, оно не делает скриншоты

Comment: @andreymal, оно скорее всего отлавливает другие действия, не то, что именно видит пользователь. В случае автора вопроса, уверен, что браузер не даст сделать скрин окна (безопасность), а делать "скрин" через html2canvas, а потом отправлять данный "скрин" на сервер - может занять много времени или вообще страницу положить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Скриншот полного экрана на чистом JS

#### Плюсы

- Не нуждается подключения библиотек, серверов и.т.п.
- Сохранение как файл прямо на устройстве.

#### Минусы

- Нужно подтверждение от пользователя.
- Если при подтверждении будут анимации какие-то, возможно их заденет.

```js
const buttonCapture = document.querySelector(`button#capture`);

buttonCapture.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true }) // Просим у пользователя разрешения снимки экрана
    .then((stream) => { // Если разрешает
      const video = document.createElement(`video`); // Создаем видео
      video.srcObject = stream; // В видео передаем поток экрана
      video.autoplay = true; // Автозапуск включаем
      video.addEventListener(`play`, (event) => { // Когда видео начнет играть
        const canvas = document.createElement(`canvas`); // Создаем холст
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth; // Задаем ширину
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight; // Задаем высоту
        const context = canvas.getContext(`2d`); // Берем контекст
        if (!context) { // Если контекст не береться
          throw new ReferenceError(`Element 'context' isn't defined.`); // Кидаем в ошибку
        }
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight); // Рисуем на холсте кадр из видео
        const a = document.createElement(`a`); // Создаем якорь
        a.download = `${new Date().toLocaleString()}.png`; // Делаем якорь для скачивая
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL(); // Передаем данные холста в якорь
        a.click(); // Активируем якорь (скачиваем)
        URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href); // Удаляем ненужную ссылку
        a.remove(); // Удаляем якорь
        canvas.remove(); // Удаляем холст
        video.remove(); // Удаляем видео
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()); // Отключаем потоки для захвата экрана
      });
    })
    .catch((reason) => { // Если не разрешает или падает в ошибку
      console.error(reason instanceof Error ? reason : new Error(reason)); // Выводим ошибку на консоль
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="capture">Capture screenshot</button>
```

#### Внимание

Пример кода тут не запустится, потому что политика блокирует.
Попробуйте у себя в сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Покажу пример, для этого нам потребуется *подключаемая* библиотека **html2canvas**

```js
  function doPhoto() {
    const holst = document.querySelector('body'); 
    html2canvas(holst, {
      onrendered: (canvas) => {
        document.getElementById('screenImg').src = canvas.toDataURL();
      },
    });
  }
  // Если надо нажать на кнопку без пользователя :)
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('doScreen').click();
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<!-- Подключается добавление одной строки к сайту -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div>Создатель скриншотов</div>
<button id="doScreen" onclick="doPhoto()">Заскринить</button>
<button style="display: none" onclick="doPhoto()">Заскринить втихую</button>

<hr />
<img id="screenImg" src="" />
```

Можно попробовать написать без библиотек используя WebAPI [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia), к примеру. Он позволяет захватывать полный экран пользователя, но от пользователя потребуется разрешение на выполнение данного действия

Comment: Без подтверждения возможно? Возможно воспользоваться navigator, выполнить скриншет окна браузера без подтверждения

Comment: @Aleks Не знаю. Надо изучать. Я с этим не работал, просто значю, что оно умеет делать, а вот все нюансы... Вариант, который я показал, может без спроса пользователей делать скрины. Ну а уже отправить файл на сервер, дело техники

Comment: getDisplayMedia, если выполнить скриншет по нажатию кнопки, браузер предложит поделиться. То есть всплывет окно, где браузер предложит поделиться.

Comment: @Aleks я кажется и метод без библиотеки нашел, сейчас попробую у себя. Если получится покажу вам.